# Change Value in Object Saved in Ionic Storage

Tags: arrays, angular, object, ionic-framework, storage

i have object saved to my Ionic Storage want to update specific value in it 
as here 
[my saved object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NkzZ.png)

i want to update only email key in this object without removing it all

if i want to update this object as below

```
$this.storage.set("user", data);
```

but this remove all user storage data and save the new one so how to access email like

```
$this.storage.set("user"."email", newEmail);
```

is that available or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear? you want to access or set?

Comment: i want to set a new value in email value which already set in user object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are using storage, you need to retrieve the object first and then change it later you need to update.

```
let user = JSON.parse($this.storage.get("user"));
user.email = "test@gmail.com"
$this.storage.set("user", JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: This example would not work as data would be undefined

Comment: @misterti just realized, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

You can read data into an object, update email field, then write the object back into storage